# Outlier detection function

Tags: python-3.x

I have created the function to detect outliers for datasets, but when I am applying it shows error, Codes & Errors are shown following.

function

```
def find_outlairs_tukey(x):
    q1 = np.percentile(x, 25)
    q3 = np.percentile(x, 75)
    iqr = q3 - q1
    floor = q1 - 1.5*iqr
    ceiling = q3 + 1.5*iqr
    outlair_indices = list(x.index[(x < floor) | (x > ceiling)])
    outlair_values = list(x[outlair_indices])
```

Apply

```
LotFrontage_indices, LotFrontage_values = find_outlairs_tukey(house_1['LotArea'])
print(np.sort(turkey_values))
```

Error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-208-4923f848f510> in <module>()
----> 1 LotFrontage_indices, LotFrontage_values = find_outlairs_tukey(house_1['LotArea'])
      2 print(np.sort(turkey_values))

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

Add return to your function:

```
return outlair_indices, outlair_values
```